# Spring 4 Hibernate validator localized messages

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, localization

I try to get working localization with custom hibernate messages but I can't make it work.
My class that is validated looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class UserEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    private String username;
```

This is part of my spring configuration:

```
<!-- Localization of hibernate messages during validation!-->
<bean id="validationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:validation" />
</bean>

<bean name="validator"  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="validationMessageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In resources I have two validations files: validation_en.properties and validation_pl.properties Here is example entry:

```
NotNull.UserEntity.username=Username can't be empty!
```

And when I am displaying validation errors I see standard message "may not be null" instead of my custom and localised one. Wham I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for help, Best Regards

Comment: Where is the validation file located?

Comment: Good point. I placed files under resources(src/main/resources). I updated my bean config but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do is `@NotNull(message = "{error.username.required}")`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class UserEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity implements UserDetails {

@NotNull(message = "{error.username.required}")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
@Size(min = 5, max = 30)
private String username;
```

In `validation_en.properties` properties file in your resource folder

```
error.username.required=Username can't be empty!
```

In spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
</mvc:annotation-driven>

 <!-- Localization of hibernate messages during validation!-->
 <bean id="validationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:validation" />
 </bean>

 <bean name="validator"  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="validationMessageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also leave a comment if this does not work for you. So I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks! IDEA for some reason defines property without { }, but not defines properties with { }. That confuses

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who has also problems to get the validator messages localized. Maybe this helps.

My property files for localization are located in `src/main/resources/lang/` and are called `validation.properties`

The `@EnableWebMvc` imports the Spring MVC configuration from `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and you can then override individual methods. (for more details see the [API doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html))

Add this to your Java Spring configuration file and your validation messages should get localized correctly:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// other configurations may be here ...

    @Bean( name = "validationMessageSource" )
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource validationMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:lang/validation");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10); // reload messages every 10 seconds
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
       LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
       validator.setValidationMessageSource((MessageSource) validationMessageSource());
       return validator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that `validationMessageSource` does not find the files:

- When you pace the files in the `src/main.webapp/WEB-INF` folder then the Remove the precursory `/` (`WEB-INF/validation` instead `/WEB-INF/validation` ):
- When you place the files in the resource folder, then use the `classpath` prefix: `classpath:validation`

for example:

```
<bean id="validationMessageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="classpath:validation" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I changed it but it still don't load my custom messages.

Comment: To check that the file is loaded, you can try to access the validation message key directly. - Just to make sure, that the message is loaded, and the you do not search for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: Use the message key somewhere - anyway - see my modified answer: the problem is the classpath prefix

Comment: I already changed it to classpath:validation but still I get default error messages

Comment: Then there is maybe some more problems.